# apt-get install fails to create dependency tree every time

Tags: apt, dependencies

Recently , we I use apt-get install to install "ANY THING" I get the following :

```
amr@Ubuntu-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo apt-get install printer- 
driver-cups-pdf
[sudo] password for amr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-34- 
generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image- 
4.15.0-34-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                              linux-image- 
unsigned-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages 
(or specify a solution).
amr@Ubuntu-Latitude-E6410:~$
```

that wasn't before, I am not sure what has changed to make this happen. is there anyway to fix this ? I try to install the mentioned dependencies every time but I get the same message . This happened when I try to install various packages , from different sources. the required packages differs every time , above is an example.

Comment: Did you try the hint `apt-get -f install`?  What was the outcome?

Comment: Yes , EveryTime, It just runs , but nothing changes after

Answer (score 2):

Well, today I had some 'fun' with something that looks exactly the same problem that you had!

This is what happened to me after trying a upgrade:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then if I tried to fix dependencies with -f...

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
... (some extra prints not relevant) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic_4.15.0-34.37~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
```

Which clame that it does not have space! quite true indeed...my boot is now full. Let's try to clean-up some space...

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Upps...I can't! Also 'ubuntu-cleaner' (janitor) did not work either...

---

### Solution...

To summarize, I found the solution in this link: [LINK - Remove Old Kernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels#Problems)
What I had to do is manually deleting the kernels...so I followed the recommended steps.

Check your current kernel:

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-33-generic
```

Print all available kernels. Choose some to delete... NEVER DELETE THE ONE YOU'RE NOW USING! (in my example 4.15.0-33).

```
$ dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+'
ii  linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic              4.13.0-43.48~16.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic              4.13.0-45.50~16.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic              4.15.0-24.26~16.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic              4.15.0-29.31~16.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic              4.15.0-30.32~16.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic              4.15.0-32.35~16.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic              4.15.0-33.36~16.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

Purge some kernels...

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -d -k linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic

$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic 
(Reading database ... 434301 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic (4.13.0-43.48~16.04.1) ...
...
```

Now, I had enough space to try to fix the dependencies...

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-43 linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-24 linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-29
  linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-30 
  ...
```

Free to go! With a bit of luck your dependencies are now fixed. You can issue your update/install as usual.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
...
```

At this step I also issue an `sudo apt-get autoremove` which actually worked and it cleaned up all previous kernels.

Please, have a look at the link for more info.
Good luck!